# Prove or disprove: if $⊢_{FOL}\exists x\forall y\ \psi$ then $⊢_{FOL}\psi\{t/x\}$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $\psi$ be a formula without quantifiers in a language with at least one constant ,
such that $\exists x\forall y\ \psi$ is a sentence.
Prove or disprove:
**If** $⊢_{FOL}\exists x\forall y\ \psi$ **then** there's exist a closed term $t$ such that $⊢_{FOL}\psi\{t/x\}$

I think the claim is correct.
I tried proving it as follows:
$⊢_{FOL}\exists x\forall y\ \psi$ **iff**
$\forall x\exists y\ \neg\psi$ isn't satisfiable **iff** (by Skolem theorem)
$\forall x\ \neg\psi\{f(x)/y\}$ isn't satisfiable (where $f$ is a new function symbol)
then I tried to use Herbrand's theorem and I got stuck.

Comment: *closed* term means that the language has constants; what about a language that has none ?

Comment: The language has at least one constant

Comment: I don't quite understand - I would think $\psi$ could have $y$ as a free variable, so then $\psi\{t/x\}$ would still have $y$ as a free variable.

Comment: yes, $\psi\{t/x\}$  would still have y as a free variable

Comment: So then, what does $\vdash_{FOL} \psi\{t/x\}$ mean if $\psi\{t/x\}$ has free variables?

Comment: for every structure M and for every assignment $v$ in it, $v[\psi\{t/x\}]=true$

Comment: For a possible counterexample if the statement allowed general first-order theories as opposed to pure FOL - consider the theory of algebraically complete fields, and $\psi := (x\cdot x-2)y = 0$.

Comment: Would it work to apply the entailment when the model of pure $FOL$ over the language is just the set of closed terms (considered formally)?

Comment: @user11: The counterexample in your deleted answer is correct! I was delighted to see it, because after thinking about the question, I came up with exactly the same counterexample. I suggest you undelete and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a counter example:
Let $\sigma=\{c,p\}$
Let $\psi=p(y)\vee\neg p(x)$

So:
$\vdash_{FOL}\exists x\forall y\ (p(y)\vee\neg p(x))$)
Because $\exists x\forall y\ (p(y)\vee\neg p(x)) \equiv (\forall y \ p(y))\vee (\neg \forall x \ p(x))$

But:
$\nvdash_{FOL}p(y)\vee\neg p(c)$
Because if we define:
$M=<\{0,1\},I>$ such that $I[p]=\{1\}\ ,I[c]=1$
and an assignment $v$ such that $v[y]=0$,
then $v[p(y)\vee\neg p(c)]=$f
and $c$ is the only closed term in the language

Answer (score 1):

<s>Yes, this is true.</s>

<s>I think it is most easily seen by using [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus) as your proof system for first order logic.</s>

<s>Sequent calculus has the nice property that everything that is provable has a cut-free proof -- and the only rule a cut-free proof of $\vdash \exists x\forall y\, \psi$ can end with is $\exists$R. ...</s>

**Ha! this is not true**, as shown by the OP's counterexample where $\exists x \forall y. \psi$ is the Drinker Paradox.
When one writes down a proof of the Drinker Paradox and eliminates cuts, what one ends up with is a proof where the last rule is **not** $\exists$R, but the *right contraction* rule. So my entire argument collapses.

(I'll let this this answer stand as a warning for the careless ...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there a way proving it without using sequent calculus?

Comment: Actually, I believe the statement is not true. There is a correct counterexample in the OP's (deleted) answer, which will hopefully be undeleted soon.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: You're right and I'm horribly wrong.